# Want to set Git Commit details as Build Title/Definition in Azure Build Pipeline

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, bitbucket, azure-pipelines

I have a Build pipeline in Azure DevOps and code repository in bitbucket.
I want to display commit details (like commit number, commit author, commit message and Name of files changed in the commit) in Build title/definition or Build Summary due to which the build has triggered.

Is there a way to do this in Azure DevOps?

**Edit:**

I'm using Bitbucket Server(Not Bitbucket Cloud) therefore I have to use other git connection(in Service Connections) instead of available Bitbucket Cloud Connection.

[image]

In the above image, I need to print the username of who has committed instead of Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.TFS.

And also on clicking the commit number it should take to the bitbucket server link consisting of commit details.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand perfectly but it will probably help you: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md

Comment: I update my build number with sha1 and branch name with: `Write-Host("##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER" + "_" + $env:BUILD_SOURCEVERSION.Substring(0,9) + "+" + $env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME)`

Answer (score 0):

If `Multi-stage pipelines` is turned off in the Preview Features, the commit number, commit author, and modified file name will be displayed in the `Associated changes` of Build Summary.

[image]
[image]

However, the commit message will not be displayed. If you need to view more detailed commit information,you need to click on the associated commit link to jump to the detailed page of the commit on Bitbucket.

You can also try to call the [commit-Bitbucket](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/commit/%7Bnode%7D) API in the Build pipeline to get the specified commit.

**Resource URL**:

```
/2.0/repositories/{username}/{repo_slug}/commit/{node}
```

Comment: I had turned of multi-stage pipeline in the preview feature and still, it doesn't show the commit details in Associated Changes under the Summary section.

Comment: The content displayed on the build summary page is as designed, and we cannot modify it, so if you want to get the details of the commit, you can try the Bitbucket Server [rest api](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/how-tos/command-line-rest/), and output it in the job log. You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions.